# Javascript regExp second match

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a string and want to find the second match:

string

```
function (typt,tyu,tyui) {
       return artigos.crudButtons(true, true, true);
}
```

regExpx

```
\(([^)]+)\)
```

The result is

```
[
  "(typt,tyu,tyui)",
  "typt,tyu,tyui"
]
```

but i need

```
[
  "(true, true, true)",
  "true, true, true"
]
```

I need to ignore first ocurrence or find after crudButtons.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please do not parse source code with regular expressions. This applies to HTML just as it applies to JS source code.

Comment: Call `exec` twice?

Comment: @Tomalak    var functionToText = '' + idx.render;
        var regExp = /\(([^)]+)\)/;
        var match = regExp.exec(functionToText);
        var crud = JSON.parse("[" + match[1] + "]");

Comment: @LeonelMatiasDomingos I am tracking regex questions, and it is the third question almost at a row about replacing/getting the Nth match in a string.

Comment: ih ih ih ih ih ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the data after `crudButtons` as

```
regex.exec(text.slice(text.indexOf('crudButtons')))
```